# Avoid duplicated content include/require

Tags: seo, php, duplicate-content

Greeting, I am aiming to do a website with a "onePage style". As I have 3 different pages I want to display, I want the first section of the page to be the content of those 3 pages and the other section would be the same on the 3 pages. But my question is : how to do that avoiding duplicated content ?
In a nutshell : 3 pages with a onepage style with the first section being different and the other section being the same. Like can you see this : https://codepen.io/guillaume-robert-the-flexboxer/pen/qgqmRm

Comment: As the answers to the duplicate question say, duplicating a small amount of content within your own site isn't a problem.   Google will ignore duplicated content.   In the worst case if the pages don't have enough unique content on them Google will choose not to index some of them.  Your site won't be penalized even if that happens.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for your response. The problem is that its like 3 or 4 section down so it is not a small amount of information. Also I want the first section to be indexed because it's important. 
To give you a picture : http://www.cordial.fr/enligne.php
I want to regroup the dictionnary, grammar and corrector with the same design, and when we scroll either we are on one or an other page we would have the same content. So the first section must be indexed, it is very important.

Comment: Google only indexes content one time.

Comment: ow, cool, so It won't be taken as duplicate content is it ?